# apt-get update in docker gets in infinite loop getting the same package list

Tags: ubuntu, debian, docker

I try to get `Apromore` up and running through docker, have the latest docker (19.03.0-beta4) and docker-compose (1.24.0) versions from their repository, I also have Ubuntu 19.04. Issuing `docker-compose up` starts the build process, but when it comes to `apt-get update`, it starts repeatedly getting the same package list and seemingly gets into an infinite loop. Any help is appreciated.

```
Step 3/24 : RUN apt-get -y update && sed -i -e '/^assistive_technologies=/s/^/#/' /etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties && apt-get -y install git && apt-get -y install python3 && apt-get -y install python3-pip && apt-get -y install xvfb && apt-get -y install python3-tk && apt-get -y clean
 ---> Running in fdd310721344
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release [92.7 kB]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release [92.7 kB]
Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release [89.4 kB]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release [92.7 kB]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release [92.7 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release [89.4 kB]
Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages [3358 kB]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release [92.7 kB]
Ign:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release
Get:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [492 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages [3358 kB]
Get:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [492 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages [3358 kB]
Get:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [492 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages [3358 kB]
Get:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [492 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages [3358 kB]
Get:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [492 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages [3358 kB]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP notes there was an unrelated issue with their VPN which, when resolved, caused this issue to go away.

Answer (score 1):

In the meanwhile it turned out that the VPN was causing the trouble. Problem solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `RUN` to these lines

```
RUN sed -i -e '/^assistive_technologies=/s/^/#/' /etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties 
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install \
            git \
            python3 \
            python3-pip \
            xvfb \
            python3-tk 
RUN apt-get -y clean
```

try again then we will see which run causes the loop